# Is it possible to add headers (and controller methods) in Symfony using the compiler pass?

Tags: symfony, symfony-2.7

I'm developing an API with Symfony 2.7 and the following bundles:

- FrameworkBundle
- SecurityBundle
- FOSRestBundle
- ... Others

In particular, I'm using the annotations @Get, @Post, @Put, @Link, @Unlink, @Delete...

My problem is browser security (CORS). I'm aware of the existence of the NelmioCorsBundle, and I've implemented a similar custom solution, but it seems ugly and too error prone.

I'm looking for a solution that allows me to take advantadge of the annotations I'm currently using to add headers and create specific methods for the OPTIONS http verb.

I don't know if it's possible to use the Symfony compiler pass because I'm not an expert... Anyone here knows if it's worth to explore this possibility?

Thank you for your time.

Comment: It is possible,  Is it worth it?  That is a value judgement that is up to you.  To me there is too much magic going on in bundles like NelmioCorsBundle and FOSRestBundle.  They work fine if your use case matches exactly but, in my opinion, tend to be difficult to modify.  I just use the basic Symfony framework capability.  Bit more typing but, to me at least, more maintainable.

Comment: If it's possible, the it's wort the effort (for me). My problem was I didn't know even if this is possible (in the negative case, spending time investigating how to do it is a waste of time). I don't like the magic, but in this case I prefer magic at "compile time" than using listeners, because that's less performant.